# react create dyamic menu by settings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-ui

I'm have side bar navigation that get a list of json

```
import {
  AppSidebarNav,
} from '@coreui/react';
<AppSidebarNav  navConfig={navigation} {...this.props} />
```

and the data is the list of items

```
export default {
    items: [
      {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        url: '/dashboard',
        icon: 'icon-speedometer',
      },
      {
        name: 'Profile',
        url: '/profile',
        icon: 'icon-speedometer',
      },...
  ],
  };
```

how can I set the list of items before they load to the sidebar ?
there is any way to use     `componentDidMount()`
to update the list ?
how should I approch this task

Answer (score 0):

Put the list of items in its own file, say, nav.js. Then add this line to your imports

```
    import navigation from "./nav"; // or whatever relative path nav.js is in.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this sample code for fetch dynamic data by **async**, **await** and  **axios** in AppSidebarNav **core-ui**

```js
import React, {Component, Suspense} from "react";
import {
    AppSidebarNav,
    AppSidebar,
    AppSidebarFooter,
    AppSidebarForm,
    AppSidebarHeader,
    AppSidebarMinimizer,
} from "@coreui/react";
import axios from "axios";
import navigation from "../../_nav";

class SidebarNav extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navData: null,
        };
    }

    async getData() {
        let res = await axios.get('REQUEST_URL');
        this.setState({ navData: {items : res });
        // OR // return await {items : res};
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        if (!this.state.navData) {
            (async () => {
                try {                 
                    await this.getData();
                    // OR // this.setState({navData: await this.getData()});
                } catch (e) {
                    //...handle the error...
                    console.log(e);
                }
            })();
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
        <AppSidebar fixed display="lg">
            <AppSidebarHeader />
            <AppSidebarForm />
            <Suspense>
                <AppSidebarNav navConfig={(this.state.navData === null) ? navigation : this.state.navData} {...this.props} />
            </Suspense>
            <AppSidebarFooter />
            <AppSidebarMinimizer />
        </AppSidebar>
        )
    }
}

export default SidebarNav;
}
```

`navigation` variable could be used for default data or loading...

```
export default {
    items: [
        {
            name: 'Loading... ',
            url: '/'
        }
    ]
}
```

In the last part call **SidebarNav** Component in **DefaultLayout** or anywhere.

Comment: hello, @ShahRokh am new to React. I've added a dyncamic menus and submenus in Core UI version 2.1.2. Now how could I show submenus of a menu on hover? Are there any props to ```AppSideBarNav``` which automatically shows submenus instead of clicking on Menu?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for anyone wondering how to do this, I moved forward by doing the following:

**Parent:**

- Setup constructor and added currentNavigation prop
- Default new prop to default navigation
- Change AppSidebarNav to use new prop
- Create a function in the parent that takes a nav object, and updates the new currentNavigation prop
- In this example, I add my navigation object to a property called `index` in a new object, this is required for the CoreUI nav it seems, however, you could do this in your child component / when creating the navigation object you will be using to update the menu.

  ```
  /** Parent **/

  import navigation from "../../navigation/_nav"

  class DefaultLayout extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
         super(props)
         this.currentNavigation = navigation //Set to default navigation from file
      }    

      functionFromParent = (yourNavObject) => {    
          // nav contains the navigation object (build this however you do), 
          // but needs to be added to { items: ... }

          let data = {
            items: yourNavObject
          }
          this.currentNavigation = data;

      }

      render = () => {
          return(
              // ...More code

              <AppSidebarNav
                navConfig={this.currentNavigation} //Added function that child fires to prop
                {...this.props}
                router={router}
              />

             // More code...
          }
      }
  }
  ```

**Child:**

- Get navigation object however you generate it to update the menu
- Pass navigation object through to the functionFromParent using props (`this.props.functionFromParent(this.getYourNavigationObject())`)

  ```
  /** Child **/
  class ChildComponent extends Component {
      // ... More Code

      componentDidMount = () => {    
         let navigation = this.getYourNavigationObject() //Get your navigation object however you do       
         this.props.functionFromParent(navigation)
      }

      // More Code ...
  }
  ```